# The meaning of "stalking dirt-floor stalls"

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning

> So much has been written about that night in the years since that fact
>   and myth have become intertwined. Regular power-outs, a guest list of
>   Beatles and Blow-Ups, acid casualties stalking dirt-floor stalls dosed
>   up on acid-laced sugarcubes handed out on the door. What does Floyd
>   drummer Nick Mason recall from that night, 50 years on? “Well
>   obviously I can’t remember a thing, so I’ll have to invent it for
>   you,” he laughs.

Here I can't understand the meaning of "**stalking dirt-floor stalls**". What is a "**dirt-floor stall**"

Comment: The "stalls" are the chair-like seats arranged in rows in front of the orchestra pit in a theatre (usually, the *cheap* ones, since originally that area was "standing room only"). But I suspect your writer is exaggerating a bit in suggesting that any such venues in the UK might really have had dirt floors in the 60s. I think John Lennon said *Those in the stalls, please clap your hands. The rest of you please rattle your jewelry.*

Comment: Okay, thanks. Stalls are chairs. Still trying to understand the meaning of 'stalking' here. Haven't seen it being used in such context.

Comment: To *stalk* has a range of senses, mainly centred on *pursue (wild game animals) stealthily*, but in this specific context it's probably pretty much equivalent to ***skulk*** *(to move in a stealthy or sneaking fashion, so as to escape notice)*, rather than ***strut*** *(to walk stiffly & proudly, to swagger)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm. Skulk.. then it should be "among stalls" or "between stalls"?

Comment: Bear in mind that originally, "the stalls" applied to the cheaper "standing room only" area nearest the stage. And even if there *are* actually seats, they're often the "flip-down" kind. The image is one of spaced out acid-heads shuffling around in that general area - some still standing, some collapsed on the floor, and maybe a few who are sufficiently physically coordinated to actually flip a chair seat down and ***sit*** on it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm. you're opening my eyes right there! Can I contact you on whatever anything you have?

Comment: The solitary downvote here (not mine) reflects the fact that this question isn't really suitable for ELU. Within reason I try to respond to @pinged "sub-questions" like yours in comments here, but I would do so much more willingly if you asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). And because there are other *Russian* speakers on ELL, you may well get more helpful feedback from them there (even if they don't know English as well as native Anglophones, they may well know more about the specific issues that are problematic for you *as a Russian speaker yourself*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I still can't get what questions are suirable for ELU. Anyway, thanks for all the help.

Comment: Well, your text is from the popular music press, so obviously the writer takes it for granted his target readership will *understand* what he writes. Not every native speaker would realise that *a guest list of [Beatles and] Blow-Ups,* say, refers to the presence of guests associated with the "trippy, psychedelic" 60s movie *Blow-Up* - but that's just a little snippet of sub-culture trivia, not "use of English". Questions about the meaning of text which is relatively straightforward to native speakers aren't really for *linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts.*

Comment: May I ask in such case? Is ELU only for natives? I guess there are very many non-natives who, with respect, ask the same kind of questions daily. I, like many others, have questions that may be understable to natives, but not to us.

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at. Why would you *want* to ask questions on a site which isn't particularly geared to your needs, when there's another SO site specifically set up to help nns?

Comment: I get your point. Learn on ELL, Teach on ELU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link to the full article](https://50.roundhouse.org.uk/content-items/nick-mason-pink-floyd-sugarcube-1966)

Elsewhere in the article it explains that the Roundhouse venue as:

> "the former engine repair turning shed and Gilbey’s Gin  storehouse"

In later days it is described as:

> "'a proper venue – one of the places that we played if we were on an
>   English tour.' That first night was something so much more."

I believe that the intention of the author is to convey how rough the venue was when it debuted...  It seems likely that the stalls were *bathroom stalls*... with dirt floors.  Am further guessing that they had to be stalked because they were hard to find, unmarked or hard to get into due to crowding.

Edit: Based on FumbleFinger's comment it seems that *stalls* could well be part of the seating area. Hard to know if they are literally dirt or not.